# Deploying a FastCGI application

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I'm trying to deploy my Wt application with Apache and FastCGI.
Here's my config file:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:9091
    <VirtualHost *:9091>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/wt_test/docroot/
        AddHandler fcgid-script wt
        DirectoryIndex wt_test.wt
        <Directory /var/www/wt_test/docroot>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Allow from all
            Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
        </Directory>
        FcgidInitialEnv WT_APP_ROOT /var/www/wt_test/approot/
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I open localhost:9091 I can see my web page, everything works.

Now I want to have a simple index.html file in my server root, and all of my Wt stuff at another location, say localhost:9091/wt

Ideally I would like to have all these things running on port 80. I already have some simple html pages and I want to create a separate location where I can place my Wt application.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Wt stuff one directory higher than your docroot.  Setup an Apache directory reference similar to how you had /var/www/wt_test/docroot in your example.  Just use var/www/wt_test/wtpgms or similar.  Then use the scriptalias directive to map it into your website url hierarchy.  FastCGI Wt seems to assume that docroot is the directory that your program exists in though.  You will need to take that into account.

Comment: I don't understand you clearly. Could you provide an example config?